# GWT - Oracle JDBC Connection problems

Tags: java, oracle, gwt, jdbc

I am having great difficulty making a connection to an Oracle Database OJDBC.

```
Error:
```

**"Unable to connect to database. Exception message: I / O Error: The Network Adapter not could Establish the connection"**

I´m using Google Web Toolkit and i added a SQL Database to my project.
The Database name is Agenda.

I've searched a lot, it seems this problem is common to many people, but could not overcome this problem.
I've downloaded "ojdbc6.jar" and added to my BUILDPATH.
I've refreshed, close, open and reopen, but I still see errors.

**My Specs:**
Windows 7 x64
Springsource - tried also in Eclipse

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Connection connection = null;
private Properties props = null;
private ClassLoader cl = null;
private String databaseURL = "";
private String databaseUser = "";
private String databasePass = "";
public void init() {
    try {
        // Load the database connection properties from com.gwt.agenda.GWTAgendaSample.properties
        props = new Properties();
        cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("com/gwt/agenda/GWTAgendaSample.properties");
        props.load(is);
        // Load the database access information
        databaseURL = props.getProperty("databaseURL");
        databaseUser = props.getProperty("databaseUser");
        databasePass = props.getProperty("databasePass");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error loading GWTAgendaSample.properties file.", e);
    }
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        // Connect to the database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, databaseUser, databasePass);
    } catch (SQLException se) { messageOut = "Unable to connect to database. Exception message: " + se.getMessage();
        System.out.println(messageOut);
        se.printStackTrace();
        // Server side log
        logger.error(messageOut + "\n", se);
        destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        messageOut = "Unable to connect to database. Exception message: " + e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(messageOut);
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Server side
        logger.error(messageOut + "\n", e);
        destroy();
    }
}
```

**Can someone point me in the right direction.
Am i missing something?**

Please help!

**Edited!!**

```
Unable to connect to database. Exception message: Erro de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erro de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.gwt.Agenda.server.GreetingServiceImpl.init(GreetingServiceImpl.java:78)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:342)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
    ... 32 more
```

> Unable to connect to database.
>   Exception message: Listener refused
>   the connection with the following
>   error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does
>   not currently know of SID given in
>   connect descriptor

Comment: databaseURL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hp-PC:1521:Agenda        
databaseUser=user    
databasePass=agenda   Where @hp-PC is my computer name and Agenda is my Database name

Comment: is the oracle listener up and running?

Comment: How can i test it? What do you suggest?

Comment: you should check if the listener is up and if it is listening on port 1521 (`Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`). Try netstat -a (from a console) and see if the port 1521 is open

Comment: Hi, I´ve tried and got this Proto: TCP // Local Network: 127.0.0.1:8888 // External:hp-PC:0 // State: LISTENING. Can´t find any port named 1521. I see a lot of Acivate rows and status Established. Don´t know if it´s supposed to happen. I remember i´ve edited my hosts file a long time ago. Is this the cause of the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems your oracle listener is not running. I'm not an expert on Oracle setup (especially on windows). Check this guide http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/OracleNetworkConfiguration.php maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I´ll take a look. If i wouldn´t be able to connect i´ll try with MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: I´ve managed to run oracle on port 1521 and connection is **Established**. now i see another error - Unable to connect to database. Exception message: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your connection is refused by Oracle database. Are you sure your Oracle database is up and running? I had a similar problem a long time ago and thought wasn´t necessary to install a MYSQL database to run a example. I was wrong and had to install to make it running.

Comment: You're right. Had not installed the Oracle Database. I never thought it was necessary. That is why it was giving the error. Once installed a Postgres database and adapted the code and it worked without unwanted artifacts. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This Error occurs under lots cicumstances:

1. No TNS-Listener configured
2. TNS-Listerner confugured but not running
3. Wrong TNS Name in the connection URL
4. More than one TNSNAMES.ORA in the system path

I had lots of fun with Oracle.
Try [tnsping](http://www.oracleutilities.com/OSUtil/ping.html) to verify your database has a connector up and running.

Comment: Sorry, do not quite understand quite well how to do TnsPing. I open a DOS window and do ping and then what are the other parameters? Thanks.

Comment: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNCET_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)PORT=1521)))
OK (10 msec)
IS this correct?

Comment: I am missing a SERVICE_NAME, but I'm not an ORACLE-professional. May be the HOST must be a hostname, otherwise the connection may be limitted to localhost.

Comment: My database name is Agenda.sql and is located in my project under com.gwt.agenda. I have no reference to it! It´s supposed to reference it´s name/location in connection string? I have also a file.proprties where resides the parameteres(url, user,pass) and are these: databaseURL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@hp-PC:1521/XE
databaseUser=marantes
databasePass=Cepsa2000. Is this also correct or have to join the database URL with url, pass and user?

Comment: The problem is not within your URL, I think. It is in the configuration of the server. As a developer I know something about the client part, but my knowledge about configuring a Oracle server is not really good. You have to ask a Oracle-admin. Try to ask you question at serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks ckuetbach. I´ll post in there, to see if anyone can help me out.

Comment: maybe I was a little bit fast with my conclusion it is a server configuration issue. ORA-12505 indicates, that the SID is unknown. Look at http://ora-12505.ora-code.com It may be the listerner "SERVICE_NAME" wich is empty or a wrong SID in you connection URL.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I see this when my DB URL is badly formatted for the driver in question or my username and password are incorrect or being passed incorrectly.

What I do is connect to the db using a db plugin for the IDE and the same driver as my code will use and get that to work before trying to connect through the code.

Comment: I´ve edited and posted the warnings and Errors. Maybe this could help understand the causes of the erros.

Comment: Your error indicates it doesn't recognize the SID.  http://serverfault.com/questions/49509/oracle-difference-between-sid-db-name-db-domain-global-database-name-service

Answer (score 0):

it is a Google App Engine problem. Run your application on an external server.

here is useful link
[How to setup GWT for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231337/how-to-setup-gwt-for-tomcat/11774112#11774112)